# Apply stochastic depth by Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

The definition of Stochastic depth was first mentioned in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.09382v3.pdf). In short, it's similar to drop-out but instead of node, it will terminate the connection of the Skip connection structure (residual block) [in ResNet paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385).

My question: is there any fast, easy way to implement Stochastic depth in transfer learning by Pytorch such as drop-out (simply add `torch.nn.DropOut(p)` into the classifier block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Basic StochasticDepth

Yes, one could do something like this pretty easily:

```
class StochasticDepth(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, module: torch.nn.Module, p: float = 0.5):
        super().__init__()
        if not 0 < p < 1:
            raise ValueError(
                "Stochastic Depth p has to be between 0 and 1 but got {}".format(p)
            )
        self.module: torch.nn.Module = module
        self.p: float = p
        self._sampler = torch.Tensor(1)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        if self.training and self._sampler.uniform_():
            return inputs
        return self.p * self.module(inputs)
```

**Please notice that**:

- `inputs` shape has to be the same as `self.module(inputs)` shape
- You can pass any block inside this function (see below)

Example usage:

```
layer = StochasticDepth(
    torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(10, 10),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(10, 10),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
    ),
    p=0.5,
)
```

## Adding to existing models

First, you should `print` the model that you want and analyze the weights and outputs.

What you're looking for to apply this module easiest (in case of `Conv{1,2,3}d` layers):

- same number of `in_channels` and `out_channels` within the block
- for different number of `in_channels` and `out_channels` some kind of projection would be needed

### StochasticDepth with projection

Version with `projection` of `StochasticDepth`:

```
class StochasticDepth(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self,
        module: torch.nn.Module,
        p: float = 0.5,
        projection: torch.nn.Module = None,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        if not 0 < p < 1:
            raise ValueError(
                "Stochastic Depth p has to be between 0 and 1 but got {}".format(p)
            )
        self.module: torch.nn.Module = module
        self.p: float = p
        self.projection: torch.nn.Module = projection
        self._sampler = torch.Tensor(1)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        if self.training and self._sampler.uniform_():
            if self.projection is not None:
                return self.projection(inputs)
            return inputs
        return self.p * self.module(inputs)
```

`projection` could be `Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=1, stride=2)` in case of `resnet` modules as it would increase number of `channels` and make the image smaller via `stride=2` as in original paper.

### Applying StochasticDepth

If you print `torchvision.models.resnet18()` you would see repeating blocks like this:

```
(layer2): Sequential(                                                                                                                                                                  
    (0): BasicBlock(                                                                                                                                                                     
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)                                                                                            
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)                                                                                                                                                         
      (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (downsample): Sequential(                                                                                                                                                          
        (0): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)                                                                                                              
        (1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )             
    )                                                                                                                                                                                    
    (1): BasicBlock(                                                                                                                                                                     
      (conv1): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)                                                                                            
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)                                                                                                                                                         
      (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )                                                                                       
  )
```

Each `layer` is a larger colored block you may want to randomly skip. For `resnet18` and `layer` specifically one could do this:

```
model = torchvision.models.resnet18()
model.layer1 = StochasticDepth(model.layer1)
model.layer2 = StochasticDepth(
    model.layer2,
    projection=torch.nn.Conv2d(
        64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
    ),
)
model.layer3 = StochasticDepth(
    model.layer3,
    projection=torch.nn.Conv2d(
        128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
    ),
)
model.layer4 = StochasticDepth(
    model.layer4,
    projection=torch.nn.Conv2d(
        256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
    ),
)
```

- First block's channels stay the same hence no projection is needed
- Second, third and fourth up number of channels and make the image smaller via `stride` hence simple projection is used

You can modify any part of the neural network using this approach, just remember to test whether the shapes agree.

### Simpler projections

One could also tie weights between first conv layer in specific block and use that `module` as a projection, see below:

```
model = torchvision.models.resnet18()
model.layer1 = StochasticDepth(model.layer1)
model.layer2 = StochasticDepth(model.layer2, projection=model.layer2[0].conv1)
model.layer3 = StochasticDepth(model.layer3, projection=model.layer3[0].conv1)
model.layer4 = StochasticDepth(model.layer4, projection=model.layer4[0].conv1)
```

**Upsides:**

- weights are not randomly initialized
- easier to write

**Downsides:**

- weights are tied and one layer will have to do two tasks:

  - be first in the block (without dropping)
  - be the only in the block (with dropping)
- this might not end up too well as it is responsible for conflicting tasks

You may also copy this `module` instead of sharing weights, probably best idea.

Comment: so what if I want to apply this to the pre-trained model, for example, `torchvision.models.resnet50`, should I re-write the model architecture and add this module?

Comment: @CuCaRot added a few examples approaches to Frankenstein the model easily.

Answer (score 0):

With the new release of PyTorch 1.11 and TorchVision 0.12.0, StochasticDepth class is now available in torchvision.ops module.

Documentation link - https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.ops.stochastic_depth.html